# Firebase Client access to your Cloud Firestore database expiring in 3 day(s)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am a beginner in the Firebase database.  I was developing my own project when I receive an email from Firebase Team saying that you have to write security rules for client access. I have no idea how to write security rules for the firebase.[image]

**HOW TO WRITE SECURITY RULES FOR THE  CLOUD FIREBASE CONSOLE?**

Answer (score 2):

Remember that Firebase allows clients direct access to your data, and Firebase Security Rules are the only safeguard blocking access for malicious users. Defining rules separately from product logic has a number of advantages: clients aren't responsible for enforcing security, buggy implementations will not compromise your data, and most importantly, you're not relying on an intermediary server to protect data from the world.

You can check this official document in Firebase [Get started with Firebase Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/get-started).